# File Not Found: cxxabi.h

Tags: makefile, llvm, abi

I am trying to compile the [hello world program](http://phasar.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/llvm-hello_world.zip) for [PhASAR](https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/phasar). I have installed LLVM version 10.0.1 on macOS 10.15.7 and set my environment flags as follows:

```
$ export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
$ export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
$ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
```

And yet, when the makefile tries to run:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -O0 -pipe -g -rdynamic  `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags` *.cpp `llvm-config --system-libs --libs all`  -o main
```

I get the error:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'cxxabi.h' file not found
#include <cxxabi.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How can I resolve this error and compile the example program?